How is the Row size too large message properly resolved when trying to restore db?
When trying to restore a mysql database, I try the following. This db is in a container
cat ~/Downloads/dbname_bkp_20240423-01.sql | docker exec -i mysql-server-main /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=password dbname

I get this message:

ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 25: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

Line 25
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accounts`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_entered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `assigned_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `industry` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `annual_revenue` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_fax` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_street` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_postalcode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_office` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_alternate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ownership` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticker_symbol` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_street` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_postalcode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_accnt_id_del` (`id`,`deleted`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_accnt_name_del` (`name`,`deleted`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_accnt_assigned_del` (`deleted`,`assigned_user_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_accnt_parent_id` (`parent_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

Any suggestions on how to handle this message?
Greetings and thanks in advance

The error message contains its own advice.

Are you restoring to a different version of MySQL?

I'm not sure but I think so

I have verified, the backup is obtained from mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2  the version of mysql where I am trying to install is mysql Ver 8.0.29 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

I think the default interpretation of CHARSET=utf8 has changed, so the strings are longer in MySQL 8.x. That's why the columns are larger and the row is too long. Try the options suggested in the error message.

@Barmar, utf8 still is an alias for utf8mb3 in MySQL 8.0. They have warned that someday utf8 may change to mean utf8mb4, but that hasn't happened so far.

No city name is that big.  Countries could be standard 2-letter ascii codes.  "Address" could be normalized out into a separate table.  UUIDs can be packed into BINARY(16).  Etc.

In your table I count a total of 2701 characters for the char and varchar columns, which means 8103 bytes because utf8 counts up to 3 bytes per character.
Plus up to 768 bytes for the text column. Any text in excess of 768 bytes will overflow onto additional pages.
That's how the COMPACT row format works. It stores up to 768 bytes on the page per CHAR/VARCHAR/TEXT column, and that must total less than 8126 bytes. But in your case, it exceeds 8126 bytes.
You can fix this by using DYNAMIC row format instead of COMPACT. That stores strings differently; if there are too many to fit on the page, it'll push all of the string onto overflow page(s), and store only a 20-byte reference on the main page.
Or you can shorten some of your string column lengths, so the total length is short enough to fit within the limit.
Or you can use a single-byte character set for some columns (where appropriate), so each string counts only one byte per character.
Or you can eliminate some columns.

Why wasn't this a problem in the original DB that they dumped from?

I don't know what instance the dump was created on.

They said in a comment: mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

I didn't test MariaDB. Maybe it has a different implementation of InnoDB restrictions. Really, I've said this before on Stack Overflow (I am sure you have seen my comments) — MariaDB and MySQL should by now be treated as different implementations. They have a common origin, but they are not compatible.
